# How to get tasks working with TBB

Tags: c++, tbb

The code below compiles but appears to get stuck somewhere in the tasks I make with Intel TBB. It simply runs and displays nothing and I have to kill the program to end it. Basically, I modelled this after an example in a book and I probably did it incorrectly. What am I doing incorrectly with these tasks? I am using g++ 4.8.4 and think I am using TBB 3.9.

```
/*
    g++ test0.cpp -o test0.out -std=c++11 -ltbb
*/

#include <iostream>
#include "tbb/task_scheduler_init.h"
#include "tbb/task.h"

using namespace tbb;

long serial_fibo(long n) {
    if(n < 2) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return serial_fibo(n - 1) + serial_fibo(n - 2);
    }
}

class Fibo_Task: public task {
public:
    const long n;
    long* const sum;

    Fibo_Task(long _n_, long* _sum_) :
        n(_n_), sum(_sum_) {}

    // override virtual function task::execute
    task *execute() {
        if(n < 4) {
            *sum = serial_fibo(n);
        } else {
            long x = 0, y = 0;

            // references x
            Fibo_Task& a =
                *new(task::allocate_root())
                    Fibo_Task(n - 1, &x);

            // references y
            Fibo_Task& b =
                *new(task::allocate_root())
                    Fibo_Task(n - 2, &y);

            // two children and another to wait
            set_ref_count(3);
            spawn(a);
            spawn_and_wait_for_all(b);
            *sum = x + y;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};

long parallel_fibo(long n) {
    long sum;
    Fibo_Task& a =
        *new(task::allocate_root())
            Fibo_Task(n, &sum);

    task::spawn_root_and_wait(a);
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    task_scheduler_init init;

    long number = 8;
    long first = serial_fibo(number);
    long second = parallel_fibo(number);

    std::cout << "first: " << first << "\n";
    std::cout << "second: " << second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you paused in a debugger to see where the execution is getting stuck?

Comment: The call to `spawn_and_wait_for_all` within pseudo-recursive code seems fishy... don't you only want to wait for `a` and `b` and not your own task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocated 'root' tasks instead of 'child' tasks. The difference is that `allocate_root()` creates independent task which does not point to anything as its successor. And thus the `wait_for_all()` does not receive corresponding signals that the tasks are completed and thus hangs.

You can find the correct original example in the [TBB documentation](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Simple_Example_Fibonacci_Numbers.html) here.

Or you can fix yours by adding `a.`.. and `b.set_parent(this)` which effectively fixes the difference between `allocate_root()` and `allocate_child()` as [I implemented here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/823aef6886862ed1).

Comment: Thanks. I will be sure to do more reading on this sort of thing.